# PHP MySql JOIN row Of Column using FIND_IN_SET method

Tags: php, mysql

I have this MySql TABLE with name settings:

[image]

i need to `select` featuredarticle `row` from title `columns` (settings table) for JOIN and FIND_IN_SET method. i try this code but i dont know how to work for select featuredarticle 'row':

```
SELECT  a.*
    FROM    articles a
            INNER JOIN settings b
            ON FIND_IN_SET(a.ID, b.title) <> 0
```

how rto select this row?

Comment: Normalise your schema!  See [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574)

Comment: @eggyal : I know this bad design, but i custom the any modules of cms And I have no choice

Answer (score 0):

you can get this like that

```
SELECT title FROM settings WHERE title LIKE  '%featuredarticle%'
```